# Runtime complexity of String.equals() in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm wondering how Java implements the String.equals() method and what the runtime complexity of such an operation is. Is each individual character checked (leading to O(N) where N is the length) or is there some kind of efficient way of comparing the two that would give O(1)?

EDIT:
As I see the other question and the answers, I'm wondering if Java has some kind of interning automatically, for example cashing some value upon initialization of the String or on the first call to compareTo or equals to allow almost all calls to be O(1). If I'm understanding correctly the answer is that one must actively intern the String and Java does nothing behind the scenes.

Comment: The source code is freely available.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, but it *might* depend on the implementation. Hypothetically there could be one characteristic shared by all impls, therefore I don't consider this question worthless.

Comment: @UliKöhler Then read the javadoc. It guarantees nothing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Some characteristics *might* not be mentioned there. I also don't think that is the case but I wouldn't really rule that out under any circumstances.

Comment: @UliKöhler So what _would_ satisfy you? If the specification and implementation don't?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If, for example, all usable implementations implemented Boyer-Moore-Horspool. This would not *need* to be in the specs.

Comment: @UliKöhler - if it is not in the spec how would you *know* that is true ... apart from looking at *all* of the implementations?  Bear in mind that "usable" involves a value judgement.  And usability is different in different contexts.

Comment: @StephenC That is fully correct, but I think it assumed the question wants an absolute judgement and info about that. I have the experience that similar question rather want to ask for *the Java impl I'm using* even if the question is not worded that way.

Comment: @UliKöhler - My interpretation is that this is an "idle curiosity" question.  It starts *"I'm wondering how Java implements ..."*.

Comment: @StephenC It wasn't so much "idle curiosity" as much as trying to understand the costs of comparing two strings vs possibly finding another way to compare two objects that have (unique) identifying string representations.

Comment: @marisbest2 - Well if you had included the details of why you were asking in the Question, you might have gotten better (more relevant) Answers ... and you might even have avoided the closure.  But I don't think so.   There is no magical "other way".  You either compare using the Strings, or you compare using the information that the `toString` method is using to generate the strings.  Knowing how Strings are represented / compared doesn't help ... except as "general knowledge".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In theory it depends on the implementation, however I don't think the differences are dramatic, for `OpenJDK 7u40-b43`, this is the implementation,

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
         return true;
     }
     if (anObject instanceof String) {
         String anotherString = (String) anObject;
         int n = value.length;
         if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
             char v1[] = value;
             char v2[] = anotherString.value;
             int i = 0;
             while (n-- != 0) {
                 if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                         return false;
                 i++;
             }
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

As you can see, it's O(n), but there are optimizations to make it Ω(1) in any of the these cases:

- the strings are the same object; or
- the thing you checking is *not* a string; or
- the string lengths are different.

Comment: there is no such thing as O(1) or O(n) its either O(1) or O(n) in this case its O(n) which is the worst case. when both strings are equal is the best case, best case does not count in Big O notation.

Answer (score 4):

`String.equals` first compares the reference. If the reference is the same as `this`, then `true` is returns. Of if the input param to compare is not `String` type, `false` is returned.   Then length is compared, if length of the two String are not the same, `false` is returned. Only in these there case, the complexity is O(1).

Otherwise, the method will compare each character of the two `String`, which means it has O(n) complexity.

Comment: You also get O(1) if the string lengths are not equal.

Comment: Note: it bails out quickly if any characters are different. This makes it effectively O(1) for detecting different Strings in most cases (unless the Strings are likely to have long common prefixes)

Answer (score 1):

You might either look at the source code for String.equals(String arg) ; or run through a debugger in Eclipse where you have attached the source.

My quick check appears to show that the strings are compared character by character.

Answer (score 0):

The "efficient way" -- standard practice for almost any Java object that supports .equals() -- is to first check for object identity. If the two are ==, then they are .equal() by definition. That's O(1).

Next, have the object implement a (cached) hashcode based on its value, and check the hashcodes for equality before going any further. That quick case is O(1) for the actual test.

In this case, if the hashcodes match the string lengths can be checked, which again would be O(1) if a mismatch can be found that way.

If hashcodes and lengths match, then you do need to do the O(N) scan to check all the characters before you can say that equality has been confirmed. (It may fail sooner if they aren't equal, of course.)

So, yes, it has to be considered O(N) in worst case. But that worst case can often be avoided in real-world execution.

(And, of course, if you can use interned strings then you may be able to get away with *only* doing the identity test. But that's a different question.)